# Why i create two records at once using django-bootstrap-modal-forms

Tags: django

I'm using django-bootstrap-modal-forms.

My forms.py:

```
class UserAppForm(BSModalForm):
class Meta:
    model = UserApp
    fields = ('app', 'app_type')
```

In view, in order to attach current user, i override form_valid():

```
class AppCreateView(BSModalCreateView):
    template_name = 'apps/app_create.html'
    form_class = UserAppForm
    success_message = 'Success: App was created.'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        app = form.save(commit=False)
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        app.profile = profile
        app.save()
        return redirect(self.success_url)
```

But, if i try to create UserApp, i get two instances at once.
Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to override form_valid() is:

```
 def form_valid(self, form):
    if not self.request.is_ajax():
        app = form.save(commit=False)
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        app.profile = profile
        app.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)
```